# Using enum in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, enums

Is this the correct (or even a valid way) to use emums in Objective-C? i.e. The menuItem is not used but just defines a list add=1, load=2, list=3 etc.

```
enum menuItems {
    add = 1    ,
    save       ,
    load       ,
    list       ,
    removeAll  ,
    remove     ,
    quit       
};

int optionSelect;

scanf("%d", &optionSelect);

switch (optionSelect) {
    case add: 
        //...
        break;
}
```

cheers gary

Comment: Added the C tag since you're not doing any Obj-C here. Just to point out that valid C is totally valid within Obj-C. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to give a semantic meaning to the enumeration, you can consider to define a customized type and declare the variable "optionSelect" as variable of that type!
In code...

```
typedef enum menuItems {
       add = 1,
       save,
       load,
       list,
       removeAll,
       remove,
       quit} MenuItem;


MenuItem optionSelect;

scanf("%d", &optionSelect);

switch (optionSelect) {
    case add: 
    ...
    break;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

That is, almost, the same thing you have written, but from the side of the developer you give a particular meaning to the variable "optionSelect", not just a simple int!

Comment: Be sure to check out `NS_ENUM` and `NS_OPTIONS`. These Apple provided macros take much the guesswork out of writing enums. http://nshipster.com/ns_enum-ns_options/

Answer (score 4):

In this, the future, it's possibly also helpful to mention `NS_ENUM`. You'd use it like:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(uint16_t, TYEnummedType)
{
    TYEnummedType1,
    TYEnummedType2
};
```

That has almost the same effect as a normal `enum` and `typedef` but explicitly dictates the integer type, which is really helpful if you ever want to pack these things off somewhere, be precise in your `struct` alignment, amongst other uses.

It was added to the iOS SDK with version 6 and OS X with 10.8 but it's just a C macro and doesn't add anything that you couldn't do with vanilla `typedef` and `enum`, so there's no backwards compatibility to worry about. It exists only explicitly to tie the two things together.

Answer (score 1):

Your way will work. However, if you would like to use menuItems as a type for variables or parameters, you will need to do a typedef:

```
typedef enum {add = 1,save,load,list,removeAll,remove,quit}  menuItems;
menuItems m = add;
[myobj passItem:m];
```